# Yii Framework - Using CCheckBoxColumn to delete multiple

Tags: php, yii, checkboxlist

I'm just trying to wrap my head around the yii framework at the moment and I've created a function to delete multiple database records at once. In the view I've got a grid with a reference to each item and a checkbox next to it

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'class'=>''
    ),
    'columns'=>array(
...
array(
    'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
    'header'=>'Handle',
    'labelExpression'=>'$data->handle',
    'urlExpression'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl(".../item/view", array("id"=>$data->id))',
        ),
array(
    'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
    'header'=>'Select',
    'selectableRows'=>'2',
        ),
    ),
```

Then further down the page I want a button (delete selected) which sends an array of all of the items to a delete function. My thoughts were it would be something akin to this:

```
<a href="
<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('.../item/bulkDelete','array("id" => $data->id)')?>" 
class="btn">Delete Selected</a>
```

But I don't understand how to get a reference for each checked item instead of :

```
"id" => $data->id
```

as I used to call pass an item to the view function earlier. If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

View:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'itemForm',
        'action' => array('.../item/bulkDelete'),
        ));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'class'=>''
    ),
array(
    'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
    'header'=>'Handle',
    'labelExpression'=>'$data->handle',
    'urlExpression'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl(".../item/view", array("id"=>$data->id))',
),
array(
    'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
    'header'=>'Select',
    'selectableRows'=>'2',
),
... //More Columns
), //End of Grid
...
echo CHtml::SubmitButton('Delete Multiple');
$this->endWidget();
```

Controller:

```
public function actionBulkDelete()
{

    if(isset($_POST['id'])&& !empty($_POST['id'])) 
    { 
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Delete Items');
            $this->redirect(array('.../item/index'));
    } 
    else
    {
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'No Items Selected');
            $this->redirect(array('.../item/index'));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the grid view inside a form, and do the following changes in your `columns` array:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'some-grid-form',
        'action' => array('myController/myAction'),
));

 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'selectableRows' => 2,
    'columns'=>array(
     array(
            'id' => 'id',
            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
        ),
    //... rest of your columns
    ),
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
  ),
));

echo CHtml::SubmitButton('Multiple Delete');
$this->endWidget(); // end form
```

And in your Controller's `myAction`:

```
public function actionmyAction()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) { //you'll get all the ids in an array
            //print_r($_POST['id']); 
            //your delete function here, also add a few validation here to authenticate deletion
            $ids = $_POST['id'];
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->addInCondition('id',$ids);
            MyModel::model()->deleteAll($criteria);
            //.... render with success flash message etc.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! this is really useful to me!

Comment: Sorry, for some reason  `isset($_POST['id])` is always returning false

Comment: @AlecGamble can you post your code, just append it to your existing question ?

Comment: I've posted my updated code, thank you again for your help.

Comment: @AlecGamble `'selectableRows'=>'2',` should be outside of `columns`, check my answer. `'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',` you will have to pass the `id` (check my answer) to get the id that is to be deleted inside controller's action.

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake. Thank you!